# How to charge a newly bought Nexus 5X(lithium polymer)?

Tags: battery, charging, nexus-5x

I just bought a new Nexus 5X, how should I first charge it? (It's a lithium polymer battery)

I plugged it in the charger and the phone turned on. Phone almost had a full charge already though (out of the box).

I usually left my new phones to charge for 12 hours before using them or unplugging them from the charger. Now I know batteries have evolved, so I'm not sure this is beneficial anymore.

I'm not sure what I'm supposed to do for the first charge and it doesn't come with instructions about it.

Any advice?

Thanks!

Comment: When I get a new device, I usually fully charge it, let it sit an hour to cool, then drain it completely, before fully recharging again.

Comment: Also worth a look: our [charging tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/charging/info). Basically: It cannot hurt to charge it fully, then simply start using it. I never made a ritual out of that – and still use my original devices with their original batteries, some for 5 years already ;)

Comment: Batteries are way better than they used to be... Use it, try to charge it at about 20% and let it charge to at least 80% if you can, if you can't, or well... The full charge/drain thing is a myth, just use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Charging a new battery for x hours before use is a "*legacy hangover*" from the days when Nickel Cadmium batteries were used. Those batteries had a "[memory effect](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_effect)". As a result, over a period of time, they "remembered" lesser battery capacity than rated capacity. To prevent this, it was advised to always fully charge these batteries
- This is not the case with Lithium Ion or Lithium polymer batteries. There is no logic to charge fully or x hours before use. Just use the battery normally, as suggested by others in comments
- [Table 1](http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/how_to_charge_when_to_charge_table) corroborates with additional information